# How to add additional fields to a file field/widget in Drupal7

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

I have a file field in Drupal 7 that I need to add additional fields to.

Currently the only available field is the file upload itself and a description.  I would like to add a title field and a dropdown with some hard-coded options.  I still require all the functionality of the file field.

How can I do this? I think I need to create a new file widget but not sure how to begin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create your own field, but it's probably overkill, http://www.agileapproach.com/blog-entry/compound-fields-drupal-7.

Personally I would recommend the Media module, sadly it's a little buggy right now.

Comment: That compound field article is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use http://drupal.org/project/field_collection

It basically allows you to group a number of fields together to a single "thing".

http://drupal.org/project/media is a different approach, which makes images, videos and so on to separate entities to which you can attach fields.